# Ajax Call to WebService returns undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery

I know that this issue has been covered a few times on here, i did my homework and checked, i tried every single solution i found, but to no avail, there must be something i'm missing.

First of all, the purpose of the ajax call: Send 3 string parameters to a method in a webservice which will save these data to my database. **If the process is successful, it returns a json string with true or false**.

The weird thing is that everything works fine locally, but as soon as i uploaded my file on the server, the ajax calls to the webservice stopped working...

First, i checked if i could access the webservice by typing the URL in the browser. I can access it and see my methods BUT, and i say but, **when i test any of my methods and click the "invoke" button, a weird thing occurs: the button click opens a new tab which sends me back to the page which lists my available methods**?!?
Anyone knows why this happens? Even the most basic method Hello World doesn't work...

i have trouble debugging the issue. I need some insight on how to debug this.

The weirdest things is that the ajax call comes back as successful, but no data is saved in the database?!?

Other information: My site uses URL routing. Don't know if this affects Ajax calls, but i wanted to mention it anyway.

I thank you all in advance for your help.

===========================================

**EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED**

There was a rewrite rule in my web.config, which adds a "/" at the end of a URL, that was messing with the ajax calls, i commented the code and everything works as expected. Let it be known that this code doesn't get along very well with AJAX calls to a webservice:

Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.myDomain\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.myDomain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

============================================

Comment: Can we see the HTML of `.whiteNightSubmit`?

Comment: Have you used `Firebug` or similar browser developer tool to inspect the JSON payload returned from the service call? If so, then please post that payload in your question.

Comment: I am using Firebug and/or Chrome's Dev Panel. Payload? Hmm, i would gladly like to but... i seem to don't know how to do that... funny thing, the alerts pop but the console doesn't write any errors...

Comment: Tried to use breakpoint with Chrome Dev Tool, and in the line alert(data.status), status is undefined and data seems to contain a HTML template looking like the default page when i acess this URL: www.mydomain.com/webservice.asmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, check the initial post, I edited it to show the solution. Thank you to everyone who took time to help me